# Tomcat 8: determine connection pool

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat-jdbc, tomcat-dbcp

In my context.xml for Tomcat 8 (Debian) I define the following resource:

```
<Context>
...
<Resource auth="Container"
          name="jdbc/UPAY"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxTotal="100"
          maxIdle="30"
          maxWaitMillis="10000"
          username="root" password="changeit"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/UPAY"
          validationQuery="select 1"/>
...
</Context>
```

I am however not clear which DB pool implementation will be used:

- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html
- http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/
- other?

How can I determine, which database pool is used by tomcat 8?
Is there a Java API so that I can do this programmatically?

Comment: the first link gives you all the answers, it especially explains why not Commons DBCP

Comment: Fair enough, I guessed so :-)
However, how can I, in Java:
+ determine the class of the connection pool?
+ access (read-only) the settings of the connection pool?

Comment: You directly cannot, your best bet is to extend from org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource, provide your custom factory and then interact with the contained pool attribute (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.tomcat/com.springsource.org.apache.tomcat.jdbc/1.0.8.5/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceProxy.java#DataSourceProxy.0pool)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource implements PoolConfiguration, I think I can try a cast or set the type in the <Resource> element.